# receive var declaration string, save value only

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to use a variable value that I get with an HTTP request, and what I get back is this:

```
var nums=["155","175","195","205","215","225","235","245","255","265","275","285","295","315","325"]
```

Which is a string with the declaration of the variable. What I want is to collect ONLY the value, not the whole line. So, in this case, I'd save `["155","175","195","205","215","225","235","245","255","265","275","285","295","315","325"]`

Is there any JQuery or JS library that can do this kind of operations with strings?? I'd want to implement an universal solution as I don't always know what will I receive in the HTTP request.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you receive this response from the API, there is something definitely wrong with it.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you get back because that looks very invalid. It would make more sense to receive a json response along the lines of `'["155","175","195","205","215","225","235","245","255","265","275","285","295","315","325"]'` which you could parse into an array using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: is this some weird jsonp implementation?

Comment: Yes guys, I know it's wrong, but this is what I receive. Thanks for the warning, but it is not my call

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = 'var nums=["155","175","195","205","215","225","235","245","255","265","275","285","295","315","325"]'
var resStr = str.split('=')[1];
var arr = JSON.parse(resStr);
console.log(arr);
```

Split the string with `=` then get the value of second position. To get array representation use `JSON.parse`

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse(resStr);` would be better after the `split`

Comment: @Liam  added in snippet ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regexp :

```
var myString = 'var nums=["155","175","195","205","215","225","235","245","255","265","275","285","295","315","325"]';
var myRegexp = /var\s*nums\s*=(.*)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

The first match group (`match[1]`) will contain your array (as a string)

If you want **the array** itself (and not a string containing the array), you can just deserialize as a JSON :

```
 var myArray = JSON.parse(match[1]);
 console.log(myArray);
```

---

As a remark, as stated in several comments, an API should not return this kind of data (with the `var nums =` part); if you don't have a specific reason for that, you should review your API.

Comment: I can't help but think that regex is overkill here. [A simple split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47285268/542251) does the same thing with less overhead

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. If the result is a string containing only numbers, then you are probably right. If the string contains some '=' signs, then the 'split' answer doesn't work. Anyway, I am not sure performance is the point of the question, and I am just providing an alternative functioning answer, as the "split" answer was already given.